# javafx How to trigger PickOnBounds within translucent area on MouseEvent

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I want to catch the mouse events in the transparent area of a node/image while hiding the stage and scene. Therefore, I rendered the stage and scene completely translucent and put an image in the center. This image has a rectangular shape and contains transparent areas.

### Setup:

- JavaFX 8
- Java 8.0.31, 64 Bit
- Windows 7
- Ubuntu 14.10/Gnome
- Debian /Gnome, XFCE

### Example code:

This code makes the stage and scene translucent (they are not rendered) and puts a red colored circle in the center. The blue bordered and transparent rectangle just marks the bounding box of the circle.

If one now clicks in the space between the circle and the rectangle's corner (which should be still in the bounding box of the circle), the click is not catched at all by the javafx program. If i change the scene.setFill() to an opaque or a color with high enough alpha (0.004 for windows, 128/255 for linux) the click is recognized.

```
package application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;

public class PickingTransparency extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        // The rectangle just helps for determining the bounding box of the circle for testing purposes.
        Rectangle rec = new Rectangle(50, 50);
        rec.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT); // The content of the rectangle should not be rendered
        rec.setStroke(Color.BLUE);      // Show the border, which makes the rectangle visible

        Circle circle = new Circle(25, 25, 25);
        circle.setFill(Color.RED); 
        circle.setStroke(Color.GREEN);
        circle.setPickOnBounds(true);
        circle.setMouseTransparent(false);
        circle.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent evt) {
                System.out.printf("Clicked at (%f;%f)\n", evt.getSceneX(), evt.getSceneY());
            }
        });

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(rec);
        root.getChildren().add(circle);        

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        scene.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT); // hides the scene

        stage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT); // hides the stage and its border
        stage.centerOnScreen();
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

I tried adding an EventDispatcher to the stage to check for incoming mouse events, but in case of fully transparency the mouse events where only triggered on elements with enough alpha.

You can modify this example to a circle with a transparent fill. In this case, clicking inside of the circle doesn't result into an event, too.

### Question:

How can I receive the mouse events on the translucent area inside of the image (circle) bounding box?

I found a workaround by combining it with swing, but would prefer a pure JavaFx solution. Could it possibly be a bug, that the translucent area is not considered within a bounding box or is it the expected behaviour?

### Research:

- [JavaFX transparent window only receives mouse events over drawn pixels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26862558/javafx-transparent-window-only-receives-mouse-events-over-drawn-pixels) seems to have a very similar problem.
- For windows I need at least an alpha value of 0.004 for receiving an event.
- Ubuntu/Debian with Gnome or xfce need more than 50% alpha in its background, the alpha value of 128/255 gets the event, while 127/255 doesn't
- The mouse events on a complete translucent window were received while using swing, so I don't think it is a general OS/Window Manager problem.

I found one possible solution at [Integrating JavaFX 2.0 with Swing and SWT](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2074496/core-java/integrating-javafx-2-0-with-swing-and-swt.html) by combining JavaFX with Swing and SWT

Comment: I could not reproduce your issue.  When I clicked on the transparent area between the circle edge and the bounding box, the click event was registered and reported by the application as per the [pickOnBounds(true)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#pickOnBoundsProperty--) documentation.  I ran your sample code on OS X 10.9.5, Java 8u25.